# How do I write a simple bare-metal program?

Tags: bare-metal

Hypothetical here: Let's say you have a processor attached to some form of USB-storage and a motor. How would I write a simple bare-metal program to tell the motor to move for 10 seconds? I want to learn how to bare metal program, and having a program to look at and analyze would be wonderful. (Any language would be great)

Comment: https://github.com/dwelch67 many bare metal examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you have to understand how the processor in question boots.  there is the core processor itself then the non-volatile storage.  for example a raspberry pi is a little unique in that there is something in logic (or an on chip rom?) that reads the sd card, boots up the gpu, then the gpu copies the arm program to ram and releases the arm into that ram.  most microcontrollers have on board flash and ram and the flash is mapped into the address space that the processor boots from and/or there is a vendor supplied bootloader that boots the processor then calls your code.

2) you have to learn how to enable and initialize the peripherals you care to use.  a timer perhaps if you want to count to 10 seconds.

3) write the application.

debugging is the trick, you can sometimes use a hardware debugger via jtag or sometimes use a rom monitor via gdb or some other program on some interface like uart.  or one that almost always is available either a blinking led or a uart to send text or numbers out to see what is going on.  and of course an oscilloscope, you can wiggle gpios or do other things and see them on the scope.

driving a motor is too generic you need to specifically know what kind of motor and how to drive it, likely zero chance you are driving it directly from the microcontroller, you might have something outside a transistor h bridge or something that isolates the microcontroller or you have a specific type of motor driver chip/circuit that you speak to either through discrete signals, or i2c or spi, or other to tell it to drive the motor, and then maybe some analog to deal with the high power or maybe that chip is a hybrid.   so you have to know all that or at least you have to know the programming side of all that, what interface and/or what signals have to have state changes in what way to cause the motor to do something.   it could be as simple as a pwm that you create that is amplified between you and the motor.  pwm may involve first learning how to mess with one of the timers then either another peripheral or a subset of the timer to make a pwm signal out of it. a  scope is really helpful here too or a logic analyzer, or if you have another microcontroller you can sample a gpio in faster than the signal being generated you can turn it into a logic analyzer.

start with finding a board, blink an led, figure out how to run a timer, accurately blink an led.  figure out the clock rates you are really running at instead of guessing, figure out how to configure the uart, send some characters out that, now you have a debug interface a knowledge of what your timer reference clock speeds are and can now try to count to 10 seconds, and then get into the signals needed for the motor.  expect to blow up a few boards, buy some spares.

Comment: some assembly is required to get a processor started and bootstrap the C code, then C is the preferred next language, you can do other languages if you want to, but it is a research project that deviates from the task at hand, all boards will support either asm only or C+asm.  for now find a board that supports c+asm. there are tons of them for under $20, with different instruction sets if you dont like arm or avr.

Comment: speaking of you can just go to arduino.cc or mbed.org you are technically bare metal but sitting on a pile of libraries that do the work for you, same experience as programming on windows or linux, just making api calls.  BUT you will find motor driver shields and motors that work with them and code that just works.    Depends on if you want to learn how things work behind the scenes or if you want to just watch the movie.  both are fun, just depends on your real goal.  making a robot to do something, or learning HOW to make a robot but probably not making one.

Comment: the arduino and mbed hardware can be programmed bare metal without using their sandboxes if you want you can take advantage of that hardware and learn how things work (take a weekend to just barely move a motor)...or you can use that hardware and sandbox environment and bang out a robot or whatever in an afternoon and make it do cool stuff.